# Make a custom JButton that can be customized?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create my own custom buttons (or that is have a template to create mine own custom buttons). What methods do I need to override to make the same sized button that the JButton makes if I want it to look that same. Because I thought that if you extend a JButton to another button class, a custom button, that had the same size and look as the JButton. But when I put my button up and in the form it makes it really tiny and does not look like a normal button.

What I want is to have at least the same looking button as the JButton has. But I also want to have the add in borders, text and color to foreground and background? What are all of the methods that I would need to override and does anyone have a simple example?

Class: (JButton) -- My Button

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class DougCustomButton extends JButton {
    DougCustomButton() {
        super();
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));    
    }

    @Override
    public void setPreferredSize(int a, int b) {
        //What would I put in here, do I need super()
    }
 }
```

Class: (JPanel)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class genericPanel2 extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    DougCustomButton b2 = new DougCustomButton();

    public genericPanel2() {
        add(b2);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 30));
    }
}
```

Class: (JFrame)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class genericFrame2 {
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(450,450);
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Not resizable");
    genericPanel2 genericPanel = new genericPanel2();

    public static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;

    public genericFrame2() {
        initUI();
    }

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {

    }

    public final void initUI() {
        f.add(genericPanel);
        f.setSize(dimension);
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setTitle("Draw Line Test");
        //addComponentsToPane(f.getContentPane());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        genericFrame2 ex = new genericFrame2();
        ex.f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Screen Shot:

My custom button is the size of a pixel? What is probably causing that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `Border` on a regular `JButton`, just like every other [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29) - perhaps add a Constructor like

```
public DougCustomButton() {
  super();
  setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
  // and a font
  Font aFont = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD);
  setFont(aFont.deriveFont(18.0f));
}
```

Read more on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) and [Font.deriveFont(float)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28float%29).

Answer (score 1):

Sizing information is provided to the layout manager via the `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` methods.  These generally delegate to the installed UI delegate, which uses, things like, the text, icon and margin properties to determine the size of the button.

Generally speaking, if you want to "customise" a button, you can use the `Action` API, which provides the means to provide a self contained entity which can easily be applied to different components, such as menus, buttons and even used by the key bindings API

Take a look at [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: What if I want to @Override the method in the new class. Do I have to call it in the constructor, or will it default to the JButton size and feel? Can someone provide an example.

Comment: What method?  It depends, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: This is what I would like to achieve for the first try at making a button. I want to at least make it look like the default button in Java? Second I would like to be able to change the size on it and that I am not certain if I have to override the setPreferredSize(...) method in the new class, in this case DougCustomButton(). Third I would like to have a list of methods that should or can be overridden to make a JButton child class? I know that paintComponent() can be over ridden, and setPreferredSize but I would imagine that there are methods that should be overridden.

Comment: If you create a `JButton` and set no text or icon to it.  I bet it will look exactly like your button does right now...

Comment: There is a way in Java to have the GUI editor open a class? How is this done. I know that if you use Open With if you already have a GUI class that will work and show you the way to using the drag-and-drop buttons.

Comment: Depends on the editor, Netbeans will all you to use any Swing based component so long as it's within its class path (so a project needs to open and compiled/build)

Comment: I think in Eclipse there is a way to just bring up and empy form with in design view but for the life of me I could not figure out how to do it last night.